# docker win 10 : localhost 403 forbidden

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, localhost

It's been one week I'm trying to display a simple index.html using Docker under Win 10. Docker is working, my docker-compose creates containers and volumes, my index.html is copied into the php container.
I added

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 dev.local.fr
```

into windows hosts, but when I try any url, localhost, 127.0.0.1, or dev.local.fr, or curl them in the command line, I get only a 403 forbidden.
This is my docker-compose.yml :

```
    version: "3.2"
services:
  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:7.2-dev-4.8.4
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./project/:/var/www/html/

  apache:
    image: wodby/apache:2.4-4.0.2
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./project/:/var/www/html/
    environment:
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html
      VIRTUAL_HOST: "dev.local.fr"
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

(but everything seems ok on the Docker side anyway...)
I've read hundreds of posts on the web and cannot find the way to reach my index.html from any browser.
I was thinking that maybe I should add some Vhosts in httpd.conf (like I was doing under Xampp or Wamp), but I didn't find this file into the apache container, and anyway I've got no idea how to add directives for Vhosts in httpd.conf from my docker-compose yml. 
But it's my personal idea as nowhere in Docker's docs it's stated we must edit httpd.conf in order to make it work.
Any help or idea will be greatly appreciated, I really need to get a working server, as I'm a pro Drupal developper...

Regards.

Comment: Maybe it's just your windows firewall?

Comment: What could be the stuff to add ? I'm using Norton. I had previous issues with it and allowed 10.0.75.0, 10.0.75.1 and 10.0.75.2 to get files copied in my volume. But what can I add ?

Comment: Possibly allowing 127.0.0.1 and localhost for the port your docker is running on? I have never really done a lot with docker so it was just a guess into the blue.^^

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found : adding one httpd.conf in the build did the trick. I needed also using a Dockerfile to make the copy.

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.2"
services:
    php:
      build:
        context: ./apache-php
      image: php:7.2-apache
      working_dir: /var/www/html
      volumes:
        - ./project:/var/www/html
      extra_hosts:
        - "pfg.local.fr:127.0.0.1"
      hostname: pfg.local.fr
      ports:
         - 80:80
```

httpd.conf :

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName dev.local.fr
</VirtualHost>
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.2.1-apache
COPY httpd.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Directories :

```
apache-php
  ¬ Dockerfile
  ¬ httpd.conf
docker-compose.yml
index.html
```

(And to be complete, I also previously allowed for 10.0.75.0, 10.0.75.1 and 10.0.75.2 in Norton Firewall.)

So I can try to build up my Drupal now. Let's hope it doesn't take another week !